# W2012 Domain and Microsoft Account

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain

Is there any way to grant access to file/resources of my Windows 2012 R2 server to an Microsoft account such as outlook.com, hotmail.com, live.ca?

Thanks Hugo

Comment: Any reason for this -1?

Comment: By philosophy and design votes are anonymous and **neither voting [up](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) nor voting [down](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-down) requires any mandatory explanation**. The tooltip that appears when your mouse pointer hoovers over the down button states: *"this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. Also questions can attract a down vote when not [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681), not quite [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) or missing details.

Comment: I do not concent to this affirmation. Any question is legitimate.

Comment: The question still remain, how my question isn't clear?

Comment: Server Fault is a site for information technology professionals -- as such we have certain professional expectations when people ask a question here, and one of those expectations is that your question is [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and reasonably well written, so not every question is legitimate. That does not seem an issue here though. But we depend on our community to answer questions and you can help by answering one of the 40.000+ [unanswered questions](http://serverfault.com/questions?sort=unanswered) before whinging that nobody's answering yours. Thanks!

Comment: So you assume that I have not do reserch before? And what about helping each other computer enthusiasts? Maybe .. "Hey you are not at the right place for your question type, go there they will help you"

Comment: 1) I didn't vote down or up on your question. I tried to clarify that we can't tell who did, nor why they they did so in response to your first comment. (You're not the only who asks such things.)  2) Although any problem YOU might have is relevant to you, I tried to clarify that not *every* question is suitable for ServerFault. My remark: *"not every question is legitimate. That does not seem an issue here though'* may have been too subtle, in stronger words, *"I don't need to close or delete your question"* Unfortunately that is no guarantee that it will be answered.

Comment: That brings me to my last point: it sucks when questions aren't answered, doesn't it? Unfortunately 1 in 6 questions remain unanswered but you can be part of the solution! Pay it forward and respond to other open questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you openly open the share with the right **Everyone**. (but currently no by design to define a microsoft account on the share)

It's a nice todo that maybe Microsoft will add someday, but when you add a security you have a *location* listbox, and Microsoft Account is not listed there. (Personnaly for security reason I don't think Microsoft will add that support, as if your employee quit you can't disable the account, you have to list where he got access to remove him, you can't monitor failed login, know if the account got hacked, etc..)

You can manually try it, the syntax is ***MicrosoftAccount\email@hotmail.com*** to define on the share security, but I just tried on a server in a workgroup and that does not work, as the location is not set correctly.

Comment: It worked on Windows 10, but not in Windows 2012

Comment: @Hugo just to know, the user in windows 10 was logged under a microsoft account too ? (not a local user)